# How to tell Stylus to not fail on missing @import

Tags: stylus

I have a project that can be packaged for 2 targets (mobile and desktop). Tho I still want to keep my source files in the same place since only a few of them are different, but the difference is too big tho to do it only with responsive method (pages missing on mobile, or totally different on desktop, ...) and I want to keep the packaged app as small as possible.

So I created a `loader.mobile.styl` and `loader.desktop.styl`, knowing that the packager will import one or the other depending on the target/platform it's building for:

```
TARGET='mobile' // or 'desktop' for loader.desktop.stylus
@import '_import' // my import helper
import('_application') // my application main stylus file requiring al others
```

and in `_import.styl`:

```
import(file)
  @import file
  @import file + '.' + TARGET
```

So the goal is, when you call `import('_application')` for example, to first import `_application.styl` and then `_application.mobile.styl` (or `_application.desktop.styl` if the target is desktop)

It is working great except that in most of the cases only the shared `_application.styl` or the specific `_application.mobile.styl` may exist and not the other.

So I am trying without success to find a way to do an **import if exists** with Stylus. If just something like `fileExists` or such was available I could do it, or a `try...catch` even without the catch block, so that if it fails it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I ended up writing a plugin which would replace `@import` directive by defining a custom `import` function. For those who it might help, here is how I did in my own case:

1. In file `plugins.js`:

   ```
   var sysPath = require('path');
   var fs = require('fs');
   // here is where I defined some helper to know what is the currently building target
   var conf = require('../config');

   var plugin = function () {
     return function (style) {
       var nodes = this.nodes;

       style.define('import', function (param) {
         var target = conf.currentTarget(),
             realPath = sysPath.dirname(conf.ROOT + sysPath.sep + param.filename),
             baseName = param.string.replace(/\.styl$/, ''),
             targetFile = baseName + '.' + target + '.styl',
             file = baseName + '.styl',
             res = new nodes.Root();
         // first include the file (myFile.styl for example)  if it exists
         if (fs.existsSync(realPath + sysPath.sep + file)) {
           res.push(new nodes.Import(new nodes.String(file)));
         }
         // then include the target specific file (myFile.mobile.styl for example)  if it exists
         if (fs.existsSync(realPath + sysPath.sep + targetFile)) {
           res.push(new nodes.Import(new nodes.String(targetFile)));
         }
         return res;
       });


     };
   };
   module.exports = plugin;
   ```
2. in file `loader.styl`:

   ```
   use('plugins.js')
   import('application')
   ```

So then any `import('xyz')` would import `xyz.styl` if it exists and `xyz.mobile.styl` (or `xyz.desktop.styl` if `desktop` is the target) if it exists.